# Python Command Line application Issue

Tags: python, command-line, python-packaging

I am referring to an example from here: https://github.com/jgehrcke/python-cmdline-bootstrap

I am able to run the setup correctly. When I run the `python -m pip list` command, I do see the package installed.

I would like to run the package with an entry point defined in `setup.py`
Any recommendations, or suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: There's a link to an article that explains how to use it in the github page. Does that have the information you need?

Comment: Ohh it was right there , Thanks @Barmar for pointing out